# redis-ha in kubernetes cannot failover back to master

Tags: redis, kubernetes, redis-ha

I am trying to create a simple redis high availability setup with 1 master, 1 slave and 2 sentinels.

The setup works perfectly when failing over from `redis-master` to `redis-slave`. 
 When `redis-master` recovers, it correctly register itself as slave to the new `redis-slave` master.

However, when `redis-slave` as a master goes down, `redis-master` cannot return as master.  The log of `redis-master` go into the loop showing:

```
1:S 12 Dec 11:12:35.073 * MASTER <-> SLAVE sync started
1:S 12 Dec 11:12:35.073 * Non blocking connect for SYNC fired the event.
1:S 12 Dec 11:12:35.074 * Master replied to PING, replication can continue...
1:S 12 Dec 11:12:35.075 * Trying a partial resynchronization (request 684581a36d134a6d50f1cea32820004a5ccf3b2d:285273).
1:S 12 Dec 11:12:35.076 * Master is currently unable to PSYNC but should be in the future: -NOMASTERLINK Can't SYNC while not connected with my master
1:S 12 Dec 11:12:36.081 * Connecting to MASTER 10.102.1.92:6379
1:S 12 Dec 11:12:36.081 * MASTER <-> SLAVE sync started
1:S 12 Dec 11:12:36.082 * Non blocking connect for SYNC fired the event.
1:S 12 Dec 11:12:36.082 * Master replied to PING, replication can continue...
1:S 12 Dec 11:12:36.083 * Trying a partial resynchronization (request 684581a36d134a6d50f1cea32820004a5ccf3b2d:285273).
1:S 12 Dec 11:12:36.084 * Master is currently unable to PSYNC but should be in the future: -NOMASTERLINK Can't SYNC while not connected with my master
1:S 12 Dec 11:12:37.087 * Connecting to MASTER 10.102.1.92:6379
1:S 12 Dec 11:12:37.088 * MASTER <-> SLAVE sync started
...
```

Per [Replication doc](https://redis.io/topics/replication), it states that:

> Since Redis 4.0, when an instance is promoted to master after a
>   failover, it will be still able to perform a partial resynchronization
>   with the slaves of the old master.

But the log seems to show otherwise.  More detail version of log showing both the first `redis-master` to `redis-slave` failover and subsequent `redis-slave` to `redis-master` log is available [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ir8ta1xtk4ijb6h/redis-failover.txt?dl=0).

Any idea what's going on?  What do I have to do to allow the `redis-master` to return to master role?  Configuration detail is provided below:

#### SERVICES

```
NAME             TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)     AGE
redis-master     ClusterIP   10.102.1.92     <none>        6379/TCP    11m
redis-slave      ClusterIP   10.107.0.73     <none>        6379/TCP    11m
redis-sentinel   ClusterIP   10.110.128.95   <none>        26379/TCP   11m
```

#### redis-master config

```
requirepass test1234
masterauth test1234
dir /data

tcp-keepalive 60
maxmemory-policy noeviction
appendonly no
bind 0.0.0.0
save 900 1
save 300 10
save 60 10000

slave-announce-ip redis-master.fp8-cache
slave-announce-port 6379
```

#### redis-slave config

```
requirepass test1234
slaveof redis-master.fp8-cache 6379
masterauth test1234
dir /data

tcp-keepalive 60
maxmemory-policy noeviction
appendonly no
bind 0.0.0.0
save 900 1
save 300 10
save 60 10000

slave-announce-ip redis-slave.fp8-cache
slave-announce-port 6379
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turn out that the problem is related to the used of host name instead of IP:

```
slaveof redis-master.fp8-cache 6379
...
slave-announce-ip redis-slave.fp8-cache
```

So, when the master came back as slave, sentinel shows that there are now 2 slaves: one with ip address and another with host name.  Not sure exactly how does these 2 slave entries (that points to the same Redis server) cause the problem above.  Now that I changed the config to use IP address instead of host name the Redis HA is working flawlessly.

Comment: Can you share how you changed that config?

Comment: It's not just the config.  I used `sed -i "s/\[master_ip\]/$master_ip/g" /etc/redis/redis.conf` script to update the config when pod is launched.  `[master_ip]` is entered in the config and `$master_ip` is the actual IP address of the master.